# reactjs redux persiste a huge amount of data

Tags: reactjs, redux, indexeddb, redux-persist

I'm working on a react redux project and persisting data with redux-persiste.
since my data become huge : I get an error in navigator : Crash out of memory

My persist use IndexedDb and my data is bigger than 500MB.
How to be able to store big size like this in redux please ?
Thank you

Comment: You can't.  Localstorage only allows up to 15mb per site. You can save urls pointing to aws for example, and store the larger data there instead and render the urls in your app instead of keeping it all local.

Comment: 500mb is way past what typical web apps accumulate (apart from the fact that browsers won't let you use that much). This is more in the realm of full-blown desktop applications.